# Reading data from xml and writing in database using C#

Tags: c#, linq

Is there any quick way to read the XML file and dump the information into database?

I have an XSD file and I created a database using Xsd2DB utility available here(http://xsd2db.sourceforge.net/) -

I now have the XML file that I want to insert into database, is there any quick way to do it? or the only way is to read/iterate through xml and insert records into database?

I tried following

- i tried reading XSD into DataSet
- I then read XML into same DS

But I don't know how to tell the Adapter to push all the tables into the database?

Comment: Shouldn't this be 2 questions:  `how to read data from xml` and `how to write data to database`?

Comment: the real question is if there is an easy way to dump an xml into database. It looks simple to read into dataset and then iterate it + run queries to save the data into database, but the real problem is the XSD is pretty complex and produces about 22 tables when I read that into Dataset, and i have been looking around for some way to save it into database by doing some mapping between dataset and the database. I looked into Linq to XML but that looks like even more coding. let me know if this helps in understanding the question and you have some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can read an xml file into a dataset and then add the dataset to a table.  How you go about it depends on your SQL server (mySql, Oracle, MS SQL).  Here's an example:

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim command As SqlCommand
    Dim adpter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim xmlFile As XmlReader
    Dim sql As String

    Dim product_ID As Integer
    Dim Product_Name As String
    Dim product_Price As Double

    connetionString = "Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=databsename;User ID=username;Password=password"
    connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)

    xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("Product.xml", New XmlReaderSettings())
    ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)
    Dim i As Integer
    connection.Open()
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        product_ID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0))
        Product_Name = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1)
        product_Price = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2))
        sql = "insert into Product values(" & product_ID & ",'" & Product_Name & "'," & product_Price & ")"
        command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        adpter.InsertCommand = command
        adpter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

You can find more examples here: http://vb.net-informations.com/xml/vb.net-xml-insert-database.htm